# Curl not performing the action

Tags: curl

I using curl to perform get operation. (this link will issue server restart )

```
curl -v -u username:password http://example.com/index.html?process=waterServer&action=restart
```

It seems curl is ignoring action part in request. I get output as,

```
*   Trying example.com... connected
* Server auth using Basic with user 'username'
> GET /index.html?process=waterServer HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic #############
> User-Agent: bla bla bla
> Host: example.com
> Accept: */*
```

Then outputs HTML page and ends with line

> [1]+  Done                    curl -v -u username:password http://example.com/index.html?process=waterServer

Is it correct behavior? If above link is copy pasted on browser, it asks for username/password and restarts the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct option working on Ubuntu is `-d`. Now command to execute is,

```
curl -L -u username:password http://example.com/index.html? -d process=waterServer -d action=restart
```

`-L` is to get redirected page.

Answer (score 0):

you have to escape your '&' in the URL parameter.

curl -v -u username:password http://example.com/index.html?process=waterServer^&action=restart

if that does not work try using curl --data-urlencode

Comment: It didn't work. I get same output `> GET /index.html?process=waterServer^ HTTP/1.1 >.` Last line is same `[1]+ Done curl -v -L -u username:password http://example.com/index.html?process=waterServer^ `

Comment: well, escaping depends on the OS you use.

Comment: just added another way

Comment: That was also not working. Thanks for pointing on escaping `&`. I have added the answer.